# WPF Get Polygon Point Coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, point

I have a WPF polygon which can have variable number of sides. I would like to get the X, Y Coordinates of each intersection dynamically.

I am able to get the Relative Point of the polygon using the below code

```
 Point relativePoint = polygon.TransformToAncestor(LayoutRoot)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

If the polygon is square I am able sort of get the coodinates by adding the Height and width to the relative point.

```
  double polygonWidth = polygon.ActualWidth/2;
        double polygonHeight = polygon.ActualHeight/2;
```

But if it is not square how can get all the X,Y cordinates for the intersection.

Comment: Why not simply access the Polygon's [Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon.points(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: The points collection doesn't return the relative coorninates. Basically, I need to be able to determine if a particular X,Y coordinate is within the polygon or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a point in coordinates relative to the Polygon, you may easily check this:

```
if (polygon.RenderedGeometry.FillContains(point))
{
    ...
}
```

---

If you are going to check that on a mouse click, you can get the relative point by calling

```
var point = e.GetPosition(polygon);
```

where `e` is a `MouseButtonEventArgs`.

Comment: I tried this solution in multiple ways. But couldn't get to work as per my requirement. The rendered Geometry does not give the position of polygon relative to the location in the window. I tried using the Bounds Property as well but couldn't reach to a solution. You have any more suggestions?

Comment: You could simply transform the coordinates of the test point to the coordinates of the geometry by one of the TransformToAncestor or TransformToDescendant method you already used.